# How to use -user argument to android backup utility bu sucessfully

Tags: backup, restore, multi-user, user-interface

I would like to restore an android backup to a secondary user. If I run from adb shell `bu help`, I see this output:

```
sunfish:/ $ bu help
 backup [-user USER_ID] [-f FILE] [-apk|-noapk] [-obb|-noobb] [-shared|-noshared]
        [-all] [-system|-nosystem] [-keyvalue|-nokeyvalue] [PACKAGE...]
     write an archive of the device's data to FILE [default=backup.adb]
     package list optional if -all/-shared are supplied
     -user: user ID for which to perform the operation (default - system user)
     -apk/-noapk: do/don't back up .apk files (default -noapk)
     -obb/-noobb: do/don't back up .obb files (default -noobb)
     -shared|-noshared: do/don't back up shared storage (default -noshared)
     -all: back up all installed applications
     -system|-nosystem: include system apps in -all (default -system)
     -keyvalue|-nokeyvalue: include apps that perform key/value backups.
         (default -nokeyvalue)
 restore [-user USER_ID] FILE       restore device contents from FILE
     -user: user ID for which to perform the operation (default - system user)
```

However, after uploading the backup file to the Owner profile (because I can not get an adb shell in any other profile), I run `bu restore -user <uid> <backup file>` but restore never succeeds.

First, I tried while logged in to the secondary user, but no backup confirmation UI shows and the restore operation times out. Here's relevant adb logs:

```
03-14 17:58:29.286 11753 11753 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.bu.Backup
03-14 17:58:29.288 11753 11753 D bu      : Beginning: restore
03-14 17:58:29.289  1493  1731 I BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Beginning restore...
03-14 17:58:29.289  1493  1731 D BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Starting restore confirmation UI, token=30388736403-14 17:58:29.289  1493  1731 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=fullrest flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.android.backupconfirm/.BackupRestoreConfirmation (has extras)} from uid 1000
03-14 17:58:29.289  1493  1731 W ActivityTaskManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent {act=fullrest flg=0x20800000 cmp=com.android.backupconfirm/.BackupRestoreConfirmation (has extras) }
03-14 17:58:29.293  1493  1731 D BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Waiting for restore completion...
03-14 17:59:29.388  1493 25093 I BackupManagerService: Full backup/restore timedout waiting for user confirmation
03-14 17:59:29.388  1493  1731 I BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] adb restore processing complete.
03-14 17:59:29.388 11753 11753 D bu      : Finished.
```

Second, I tried when logged in to the Owner profile. I get a confirmation prompt, but it also fails. Here's the adb logs:

```
03-14 18:00:39.448 11948 11948 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.bu.Backup
03-14 18:00:39.450 11948 11948 D bu      : Beginning: restore
03-14 18:00:39.451  1493  2786 I BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Beginning restore...
03-14 18:00:39.451  1493  2786 D BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Starting restore confirmation UI, token=606614021
03-14 18:00:39.451  1493  2786 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=fullrest flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.android.backupconfirm/.BackupRestoreConfirmation (has extras)} from uid 1000
03-14 18:00:39.451  1493  2786 W ActivityTaskManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { act=fullrest flg=0x20800000 cmp=com.android.backupconfirm/.BackupRestoreConfirmation (has extras) }
03-14 18:00:39.459  1493  1994 W ActivityTaskManager: Tried to set launchTime (0) < mLastActivityLaunchTime (22366588)
03-14 18:00:39.462  1493  2786 D BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] Waiting for restore completion...
03-14 18:00:39.572  1493  1757 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.android.backupconfirm/.BackupRestoreConfirmation: +112ms
03-14 18:00:43.431  1493  5565 D BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] acknowledgeAdbBackupOrRestore : token=606614021 allow=true
03-14 18:00:43.432  1493  5565 W BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] Attempted to ack full backup/restore with invalid token
03-14 18:00:46.213  1493  2063 D InputDispatcher: Waiting to send key to Window{200410c u0 com.android.backupconfirm/com.android.backupconfirm.BackupRestoreConfirmation} because there are unprocessed events that may cause focus to change
03-14 18:01:39.563  1493 25093 I BackupManagerService: Full backup/restore timed out waiting for user confirmation
03-14 18:01:39.563  1493  2786 I BackupManagerService: [UserID:11] adb restore processing complete.
03-14 18:01:39.564 11948 11948 D bu      : Finished.
```

An acceptable answer includes details steps taken to get the restore to succeed for the secondary user. This should work on stock android. I prefer android 11, but I'll accept any version as that would indicate that it did work at one time.

Comment: have you tried adb restore?

Comment: Yes, and it appears that `adb restore` does not accept the `-user` argument. It just hangs, iirc. Does it work for you?